# Tensorflow 2.1 full memory and tf.function called twice

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm developing a Convolutional Autoencoder with Tensorflow 2.1.

This is the code

```
class ConvAutoencoder:

def __init__(self, input_shape, latent_dim):
    self.input_shape = input_shape
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.__create_model()

def __create_model(self):
    # Define Encoder
    encoder_input = Input(shape=self.input_shape, name='encoder_input')
    x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_input)
    x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    last_conv_shape = x.shape
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(units=self.latent_dim, name='encoded_rep')(x)
    self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, x, name='encoder_model')
    self.encoder.summary()

    # Define Decoder
    decoder_input = Input(shape=self.latent_dim, name='decoder_input')
    x = Dense(units=256)(decoder_input)
    x = Dense(units=(last_conv_shape[1] * last_conv_shape[2] * last_conv_shape[3]), activation='relu')(x)
    x = Reshape(target_shape=(last_conv_shape[1], last_conv_shape[2], last_conv_shape[3]))(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=self.input_shape[2], kernel_size=5, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, x, name='decoder_model')
    self.decoder.summary()

    # Define Autoencoder from encoder input to decoder output
    self.autoencoder = Model(encoder_input, self.decoder(self.encoder(encoder_input)))
    self.optimizer = Adam()
    self.autoencoder.summary()


@tf.function
def compute_loss(model, batch):
    decoded = model.autoencoder(batch)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(batch - decoded), axis=[1, 2, 3]))


@tf.function
def train(train_data, model, epochs=2, batch_size=32):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_data), batch_size)):
            batch = train_data[i: i + batch_size]
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                loss = compute_loss(model, batch)
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables)
            model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img_dim = 64
    channels = 1

    (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
    # Resize images to (img_dim x img_dim)
    x_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_dim, img_dim)) for img in x_train])
    x_test = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_dim, img_dim)) for img in x_test])

    # Normalize images
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

    # Reshape datasets for tensorflow
    x_train = x_train.reshape((-1, img_dim, img_dim, channels))
    x_test = x_test.reshape((-1, img_dim, img_dim, channels))

    # Create autoencoder and fit the model
    autoenc = ConvAutoencoder(input_shape=(img_dim, img_dim, channels), latent_dim=4)

    # Train autoencoder
    train(train_data=x_train, model=autoenc, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Now, the problems are two:

- The function `train()`, which is labeled with `@tf.function` is called twice. This doesn't happen without the `@tf.function` label
- Each epoch of training increases the memory consumption by around 3GB

What am I doing wrong?

Other info:

- Tensorflow version: 2.1.0
- Python version 3.7.5
- Tensorflow is not using GPU since I still have driver problems

There's nothing much to say in addition but StackOverflow is forcing me to write something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your **First problem**, when you use `@tf.function`, the function is executed and traced. 
During this **Eager execution** is disabled in this context, therefore every `tf. method` just defines a `tf.Operation` node that produces a `tf.Tensor` output.

**Code debugging 1 :**

```
# Train autoencoder
    train(train_data=x_train, model=autoenc, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

*Note: Increased epochs to **5** with **shorter dataset** for better debugging.*

**Train Function:**

```
@tf.function
def train(train_data, model, epochs=2, batch_size=32):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
      print("Python execution: ", epoch)   ## This Line only Prints during Python Execution
      tf.print("Graph execution: ", epoch) ## This Line only Print during Graph Execution

      # for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_data), batch_size)): ## RAISES ERROR
      for i in range(0, len(train_data), batch_size):
          batch = train_data[i: i + batch_size]
          with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
              loss = compute_loss(model, batch)
          gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables)
          model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables))
```

[image: tf_function_exec_5epoch]
Here is the output of your original code when debugged with **Python**  `print( )` and **Tensorflow** print `tf.print( )` function. 
You can see that the function looks like "executed" **twice**, but it is for tracing and execution to build the Graph, but the **succeeding calls** for this function is already using the **AutoGraph** generated.

Observing this, It is better to use the **epoch outside the training loop** when optimizing with `@tf.function`.

**Code debugging 2 :**

```
    # Train autoencoder
    epochs = 5
    print('Loop Training using Dataset (Epochs : {})'.format(epochs))
    for epoch in range(epochs):
      train(train_data=x_train, model=autoenc, batch_size = 32)
```

**Train Function:**

```
@tf.function
def train(train_data, model, batch_size=32):
      print("Python execution")   ## This Line only Prints during Python Execution
      tf.print("Graph execution") ## This Line only Print during Graph Execution

      # for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_data), batch_size)):
      for i in range(0, len(train_data), batch_size):
          batch = train_data[i: i + batch_size]
          with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
              loss = compute_loss(model, batch)
          gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables)
          model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.autoencoder.trainable_variables))
      print("#################") # For Debugging Purpose
```

[image: tf_outsideloop_epoch5]
Here is the output of the **modified flow** and **function**, you can **still** see that the function is "executed" **twice**. And executes the training using the **AutoGraph** built for the **5 Epochs**.
Here every succeeding call for train function is already **executed in Graph**, resulting in a **shorter time** of execution due to Tensorflow Optimizations.

For your **Second problem**, with regards to **running out of memory**.

You could try using **Tensorflow Dataset Generators**, rather than loading your **entire** Dataset in **memory**.

You could read more about this in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).